# In IE, how can I find the coordinates of an <option> element within a <select> element?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have the following HTML code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Cheeses</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select name="multi" id="multi" multiple="multiple">
        <option selected="selected" label="emmental">Emmental</option>
        <option label="roquefort" >Roquefort</option>
        <option label="parmigiano">Parmigiano</option>
        <option label="cheddar">Cheddar</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

In JavaScript in IE, how do I get the dimensions and position of one of the `<option>` elements? Doing the following doesn't work:

```
var selectEl = document.getElementById("multi");
var options = selectEl.getElementsByTagName("option");
var rect = options[1].getBoundingClientRect();
```

A rect is returned, but it has zero for all properties of the rect. I would prefer a straight JavaScript solution, not relying on a library like JQuery, but if I have to, I'd accept a JQuery answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options won't have any dimensions, the containing select element has the width & height.

```
var width = select.style.width
var height = select.style.height
```

Calculating the screen position is trickier because you have the work out the offset widths and heights of the parent elements.

jQuery has methods that work out these values, but they aren't always that accurate.

Comment: So, you're saying the answer is, "you can't do it". The `<select>` element's dimensions are of no use to me. It's a multi-select list, and I need to know the coordinates of the options for use within a [browser automation framework](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/).

Comment: getBoundingClientRect() works in Firefox 3.5+ but in Internet Explorer 7 & 8 it isn't supported. Not sure about Internet Explorer 9, I don't have a copy to hand. It isn't supported on Chrome either